# Rake db problem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

```
C:\Ruby\apps\sample>rake db:create:all
(in C:/Ruby/apps/sample)
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.8/lib/active_record/connection
_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:44: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
```

-- control frame --------------

Major error I think and I don't know how to fix this.

I am running on Windows XP. I also copied the libmysql.dll to C:\Ruby\bin. I have already gone to a lot of forums none helps.

```
Rails version - 3.0.8
MySQL version - 5.1
```

Thanks for those who can answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the MySQL dll on Windows with version 5.1. You'll need to use the dll for version 5.0 as explained here (among others) : http://www.fuyun.org/2010/01/ruby-mysql-adapter-on-windows/